# Speeding up performance when writing from pandas to sqlite

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, cython

Hoping for a few pointers on how I can optimise this code up... Ideally I'd like to keep with using pandas but assume there's some nifty sqlite tricks I can use to get some good speed-up. For additional "points", would love to know if Cython could help at all here?

Incase it's not obvious from the code.. for context, I'm having to write out millions of very small sqlite files (files in "uncompressedDir") and outputting them into a much larger "master" sqlite DB ("6th jan.db").

Thanks in advance everyone!

```
%%cython -a

import os
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import time
import sys

def main():

    rootDir = "/Users/harryrobinson/Desktop/dataForMartin/"
    unCompressedDir = "/Users/harryrobinson/Desktop/dataForMartin/unCompressedSqlFiles/"

    with sqlite3.connect(rootDir+'6thJan.db') as conn:

        destCursor = conn.cursor()

        createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userData(TimeStamp, Category, Action, Parameter1Name, Parameter1Value, Parameter2Name, Parameter2Value, formatVersion, appVersion, userID, operatingSystem)"
        destCursor.execute(createTable)


    for i in os.listdir(unCompressedDir):

        try:
            with sqlite3.connect(unCompressedDir+i) as connection:
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Events')
                df_events = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
                cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Global')
                df_global = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())

                cols = ['TimeStamp', 'Category', 'Action', 'Parameter1Name', 'Parameter1Value', 'Parameter2Name', 'Parameter2Value']
                df_events = df_events.drop(0,axis=1)
                df_events.columns = cols

                df_events['formatVersion'] = df_global.iloc[0,0]
                df_events['appVersion'] = df_global.iloc[0,1]
                df_events['userID'] = df_global.iloc[0,2]
                df_events['operatingSystem'] = df_global.iloc[0,3]

        except Exception as e:
            print(e, sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno)

        try:
            df_events.to_sql("userData", conn, if_exists="append", index=False)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Sqlite error, {0} - line {1}".format(e, sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno))
```

**UPDATE**: halved the time by adding a transaction instead of to_sql

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to profile things to see whether the performance problem is caused by Pandas, sqlite itself. or SQLAlchemy (which IIRC is what Pandas uses to talk to the database). I'm pretty sure there's a way to get pandas to dump the SQL statements instead of/in addition to executing them, in which case you could do the first step very easily by just executing those SQL statements directly and comparing the total times… but I don't remember how to get it to dump them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconsider using Pandas as a staging tool (leave the library for data analysis). Simply write pure SQL queries which can be accommodated by using SQLite's [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) to query external databases.

```
with sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(rootDir,'6thJan.db')) as conn:

        destCursor = conn.cursor()

        createTable = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userData(
                            TimeStamp TEXT, Category TEXT, Action TEXT, Parameter1Name TEXT, 
                            Parameter1Value TEXT, Parameter2Name TEXT, Parameter2Value TEXT, 
                            formatVersion TEXT, appVersion TEXT, userID TEXT, operatingSystem TEXT
                         );"""

        destCursor.execute(createTable)
        conn.commit()

        for i in os.listdir(unCompressedDir):

             destCursor.execute("ATTACH ? AS curr_db;", i)

             sql = """INSERT INTO userData
                      SELECT e.*, g.formatVersion, g.appVersion, g.userID, g.operatingSystem
                      FROM curr_db.[events] e
                      CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM curr_db.[global] LIMIT 1) g;"""

             destCursor.execute(sql)
             conn.commit() 

             destCursor.execute("DETACH curr_db;")
```